# Set selected index on Dropdownlist in Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

My issue is that I need to set the selected value of a nested DropDownList inside a Telerik MVC Grid Control. Since the grid is bound on the client I need to set the selected item of the dropdown list in the "onDrpLoad" event on the client.

What would be the correct way to set the selected index for the dropdown list below? It is also important that when the selected item in the dropdown list is set is does NOT cause the "onDrpChange" event to fire. The "onDrpChange" event also needs to access(send to the server) the AssistantId of the assistant that was selected when the event fires.

Is there a clean simple way to do this?

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<Person>().Name("Grid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax).Select("GetDetails", "Person"))
    .Columns(columns => columns.Bound(p => p.AssistantId).ClientTempalate(
        Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("AssistantList_<#= PersonId #>").BindTo(new
            SelectList(AssistantController.GetAssistants))).ClientEvents(events => events.OnLoad("onDrpLoad"); events.OnChange("onDrpChange");
        ).ToHtmlString());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. (Already used this approach in the past, it works)

Instead of creating your SelectList in the DropDown declaration, make it a property of your model.

```
public class YourPageViewModel
{
    public YourPageViewModel()
    {
        this.YourSelectList = <fill the list>;
        this.SelectedItemIndex = <index of the item you want to be selected in the list>;
    }

    public SelectList YourSelectList { get; set; }

    public int SelectedItemIndex { get; set; }
}
```

At the top of your view your have :

```
@model YourPageViewModel
```

Then your DropDown declaration :

```
Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("AssistantList_<#= PersonId #>")
    .BindTo(Model.YourSelectList).SelectedIndex(Model.SelectedItemIndex)
    .ClientEvents(events => 
    {
        events.OnLoad("onDrpLoad"); 
        events.OnChange("onDrpChange");
    })
    .ToHtmlString()
```

Comment: I have decided to go with the new Foreign column feature to resolve this issue. The only drawback is that I have to add a new column for the Edit command button.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Because my Grid was bound on the client (i.e. used Ajax Binding) and got the items data from the select command ("GetDetails") there wasno need to expose this list on my model. My issue is that on the server when the view model object is constructed you have no idea which item is going to be displayed in the row which in turn means that if you have a server side bound dropdownlist you can only set the selected index on the client.FYI-I used the ForeignKey column feature on the Telerik Grid control to resolve this issue. Downside is I now need a "command button column".